# SQLConnect fails in service but not when executed from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I have an  application which I'm trying to make to work on windows 10, connected to a database MSSQL 2008 R2 that I run into a virtual machine.

Everything works if I run it from inside visual studio or from outside it, but if I try to to start it as a service from "Services", then SQLConnect returns -1 which is SQL_NULL_DATA.

Googling the problem didn't helped at all. I wouldn't mind running it as not a service, but the thing is designed as a service and just closes when GetMessageA from winapi returns 0, which it does.

```
  SQLRETURN ret;

  ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &m_henv);
  if (TSQL_FAIL(ret))
    return FALSE;

  ret = SQLSetEnvAttr(m_henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
  if (TSQL_FAIL(ret)) {
    Close();
    return FALSE;
  }

  ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_henv, &m_hdbc);
  if (TSQL_FAIL(ret)) {
    Close();
    return FALSE;
  }

  ret = SQLConnect(m_hdbc,
    (SQLCHAR*) dsn, SQL_NTS,
    (SQLCHAR*) user, SQL_NTS,
    (SQLCHAR*) passwd, SQL_NTS);
  // here it fails, returning -1
  if (TSQL_FAIL(ret)) {
    Close();
    return FALSE;
  }
```

I have the DNS configured in 32 bit odbc to point to the database inside the vm.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Check that the account the service is running under has permission to access the network.

Comment: Aparently I totally missed that there were 2 dns that had to be configured in odbc and I only configured one. Aand now it works.